# How many concurrent connections will be handled by Squid proxy

Tags: linux, networking, permissions, performance, proxy

I am running opensource Squid proxy on port 3128. Sometimes squid proxy PID goes to nonresponsive state and after that sometimes Squid returns back to responsive state.

Could you tell me how many concurrent connections Squid can handle at the same time?

Will Squid proxy depend on system hardware resources?

Note: Sometimes I could see more ESTABLISHED connections for "Squid port 3128"

Answer (score 5):

As of 2013:

> The limit on number of connections any Squid can have attached is 
>   only limited by your configured FD limits and available server RAM. 
>   Squid uses ~64 KB per network socket for traffic state - which equates 
>   to around 2 GB of RAM just for I/O buffers at 20,000 concurrent client 
>   connections.

[source](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201302/0304.html)

Comment: I have 8GB RAM and 2 vcpu , I have used FD limit is 65535 and max user process is 1024 .. what i need to fine in the system configuration.